# Cache External API calls - Django

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
import requests 
   
URL = "http://www.test.com/products"
  
r = requests.get(url = URL) 
  
data = r.json()
```

I want to integrate this task into Django rest application,and want to call this as seperate service, and i want to make sure this external API should not be called on every page load, how can we achieve this?

just using of django Local-memory cache in settings.py and cache decorator on my view will resolve this issue ?, I just need idea, which is better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method_decorator and cache_page decorators. [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/)

cache_page decorator caches view output so there will be no unnecessary requests to the third-party API.

Don't forget to pre-configure your [caching system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/)

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets

class TestViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*2))
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'detail': 'success'})
```